# Why am I only extracting one value out of my variadic template?

Tags: c++

I am writing a program that will act as a controller between classes. Essentially, the classes all have getters and setters, however, the getters and setters have different names and some perform different actions. For example `ClassA` has a setter `setValue`, but `ClassB` has a setter named `updateValue`. These classes are already written and I don't want to rewrite each one to have the same name because they are embedded within the code base already. Instead, I have written a `updateVariable` function in each class that will call it's respective setter.

Now that I have that explanation out of the way, I will show the controller class:

```
#ifndef CONTROLLER_HPP
#define CONTROLLER_HPP

#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Controller
{

  public:
    template <class...Classes>
    Controller(Classes & ...classes) 
    { 
      toSet = [&](int val){(classes.updateValue(val), ...); }; 
      toGet = [&](){ return (classes.get(), ...); }; 
    }

    void setValues(int val)
    {
      toSet(val);
    }

    std::vector<int> getValues()
    {
      std::vector<int> values;
      values.emplace_back(toGet());
      return values;
    }

  private:
    std::function<void(int)> toSet;
    std::function<int()> toGet;
};

#endif
```

I am still not sure how `toSet` works, For example, if I declare this in main:

```
int main()
{
  ClassA a;
  ClassB b;
  ClassC c;
  Controller control(A,B,C);
  control.setValues(20);
}
```

This would set the values of all of the classes to 20. But I do not know how the magic works since it only seems to be called once. However, when I tried the same thing with `toGet`, I only get one value back. So I am confused on why this isn't working.

Comment: Please improve your questions, instead of deleting your older ones, and ask a new one for each time you edit.

Answer (score 0):

#### Explatation

In C++, putting a comma between statements discards the return value of everything except the last statement:

```
int x = (10, 20, "Hello", 30); 
// x is 30
```

The comma operator is used in two places. Here, with `toSet`:

```
toSet = [&](int val){(classes.updateValue(val), ...); };
```

And here, with `toGet`:

```
toGet = [&](){ return (classes.get(), ...); };
```

`toSet` works fine because you don't care about the return value of `updateValue`. All you do is update the value. However, `toGet` only returns the last value passed in.

#### The fix

If `get()` always returns the same type (e.g., int) for all classes, We can modify `toGet` to return a vector instead:

```
// Declaration: 
// std::function<std::vector<int>()> toGet; 
toGet = [&]() { return std::vector<int>{classes.get()...}; };
```